# net-snmp mfd implemented writable objects

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I am trying to extend agent to support my mib. I was using old api before but this time I decided going into the newer one. So I started by using mib2c.mfd.conf as mib2c configuration file and after some effort by following ifTable tutorial in net-snmp site I succeeded in processing get requests. But in the case of set requests I face the error:

```
Error in packet.
Reason: notWritable (That object does not support modification)
Failed object: ZT400-CONF-MIB::nodeLoc.1
```

and no debugging log is outputted by my agent. (In the case of get I receive something like this):

```
internal:nodeTable:_mfd_nodeTable_pre_request: called
verbose:nodeTable:nodeTable_pre_request: called
internal:nodeTable:_mfd_nodeTable_object_lookup: called
verbose:nodeTable:nodeTable_row_prep: called
internal:nodeTable:_mfd_nodeTable_get_values: called
internal:nodeTable:_mfd_nodeTable_get_column: called for 2
verbose:nodeTable:nodeName_get: called
internal:nodeTable:_mfd_nodeTable_post_request: called
verbose:nodeTable:nodeTable_post_request: called
```

And for set request as it stated in read-me file I expect receiving at least first two lines.
what is the problem? can anyone help?
Is there a working tutorial for implementing snmp settable objects with net-snmp mfd?